How to make an HTML element cover the edge of the screen without leaving any space?
I made a section list and I want it to cover 100% of the left side of the page but it still leaves some space at the edge. 
As you can see, the div leaves some space at the  left side of the screen. How do I fix this?
Here's the code I used:


#sectionList {
            background-color: #131067;
            height: 100%;
            width: 500px;
        }
<div id="sectionList"></div>




In addition to checking out the linked answer, learn how to use your browser developer tools. They can tell you where a style comes from. You can always override default styles.

There are default padding and margin for the <body> element, depending on your browser. Here, I set them to 0 and also set width and height to be 100% of the viewport.


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#sectionList {
  background-color: #131067;
  /*
  height: 100%;
  width: 500px;
  */
  
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
<div id="sectionList">
  hello
</div>



